# $E$-field of moving charge and transforming between frames

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-fields, inertial-frames

Let's say we are in the lab frame and have a charge $e$ moving at velocity $\vec{v} = v_0 \hat{x}$. In the charge's frame of reference (primed frame) it produces an E field of $\vec{E'} = \frac{e}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {r'}^2}\hat{r'}$, and has a parallel component ${E'_{\parallel }} = \frac{e}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {r'}^2}$. If I want to find the E field at a position $x' \hat{x}$ away from the particle, I think it is ${E'_{\parallel }} = \frac{e}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {x'}^2}$.

Now I want to know what the E field at this position is in the unprimed frame. We know the E fields transform with ${E'_{\parallel }} = E_{\parallel }$. In the lab frame, lengths in the particles frame are contracted, so I would expect ${x' = \frac{1}{\gamma}x}$. I would then think

$${E_{\parallel }} = {E'_{\parallel }}=\frac{e}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {x'}^2} = \frac{e}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {(\frac{1}{\gamma}x})^2} = \frac{e \gamma^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {x}^2} .$$

However, using the equation derived in Purcell and Morin (p. 238, 3rd ed.), $${E_{\parallel}} = \frac{e}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {x}^2} (1-\beta^2) = \frac{1}{\gamma^2} \frac{e}{4\pi \epsilon_0 {x}^2}.$$

I'm  on board with Purcell's equation being correct, so I think I'm applying length contraction wrong. How should we transform between these two frames?

Answer (score 0):

A rod of length $L$ in its rest frame will be contracted and measure $L/\gamma$ in the lab frame. Therefore your lab frame $x$ is equal to
$x'/\gamma$. Substituting $x'=\gamma x$
gives the  Purcell and Morin's result.